# How to setAttribute correctly to make sure the function call for a specific element in the array?

Tags: javascript

For some reason when I use the 'click' it does not recognise the right card from the array I created in the beginning.
In the console, it only shows me "undefined" instead of the rank, suit and the path to the src.

I try to think if maybe I shouldn't use this.

```
const cards = [{
    rank: "queen",
    suit: "hearts",
    cardImage: "images/quees-of-hearts.png",
  },
  {
    rank: "queen",
    suit: "diamonds",
    cardImage: "images/queen=of-diamonds.png",
  },
  {
    rank: "king",
    suit: "hearts",
    cardImage: "images/king-of-hearts.png",
  },
  {
    rank: "king",
    suit: "diamonds",
    cardImage: "images/king-of-diamonds.png",
  }
];
const cardsInPlay = [];

function checkForMatch() {
  this.setAttribute('src', cards.cardImage);
  if (cardsInPlay.length === 2) {
    if (cardsInPlay[0] === cardsInPlay[1]) {
      alert("You found a match!");
    } else {
      alert("Sorry, try again.");
    }
  }
}

function flipCard() {
  //this.getAttribute('data-id');
  console.log("User flipped " + cards.rank);
  console.log(cards.cardImage);
  console.log(cards.suit);
  cardsInPlay.push(cards.rank);
  checkForMatch();

}

function createBoard() {
  for (var i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
    var cardElement = document.createElement('img');
    cardElement.setAttribute('src', 'images/back.png');
    cardElement.setAttribute('data-id', i);
    cardElement.addEventListener('click', flipCard);
    document.getElementById('game- 
      board ').appendChild(cardElement);
    }
  }
  createBoard();
```

Comment: `cards.cardImage` That won't work - `cards` is an array, you need to access a specific element in the array first - like `cards[1].cardImage`.

Comment: Okay, that sounds logical.
How can I call the card I clicked on? Have any advice for that?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```js
this.src = "cards.cardImage"
```

I don't think setAttribute will work in this case.

Answer (score 0):

```
    function checkForMatch(selectedCard) {
        cardNumber = selectedCard.getAttribute('data-id');
        selectedCard.setAttribute('src', cards[cardNumber].cardImage);
        if (cardsInPlay.length === 2) {
            if (cardsInPlay[0] === cardsInPlay[1]) {
                alert("You found a match!");
            } else {
                alert("Sorry, try again.");
            }
        }
    }

    function flipCard() {
        cardNumber = this.getAttribute('data-id');
        console.log(cardNumber);
        console.log("User flipped " + cards[cardNumber].rank);
        console.log(cards[cardNumber].cardImage);
        console.log(cards[cardNumber].suit);
        cardsInPlay.push(cards[cardNumber].rank);
        checkForMatch(this);
    }
```

Your addEventListener is calling flipcard, so within flipcard you can use `this`, which you then pass to `checkForMatch`. So from there you can use `selectedCard` instead of this. And as someone else mentioned, cards is an array so you have to access it like `cards[cardNumber].rank` etc

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. 
Since I am very new in this there is one thing I do not understand - how can I attach the [cardNumber] from the flip card - I tried to use i, but it is not recognised, so I that is where I am stuck right now. Since I do not know the cardNumber, how can I go over it?

Comment: @Mathsteacher7 Hi, cardNumber is defined in flipCard, then you call `checkForMatch(this)`. Then `checkForMatch(selectedCard)` pulls in `this` as `selectedCard`, and you define `cardNumber` again based on `selectedCard`. You can kind of think of `selecetedCard` as the new `this` for that function. Hope that helps.